# PDF not getting rendered in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

We are working on ng2-pdf-viewer to display local pdf files in offline mode.ng2-pdf-viewer was unable to load and view pdf files from the local directory of android.Example src may look like this file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/abc.pdf.We are doing this in Ionic 3.Did not find any resource on how to work with local files of the above format in ng2-pdf-viewer.Please suggest

Comment: any solutions for this?